# Printing pdf files from windows mobile

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, windows-mobile

I've used a third party library (iText) to create a PDF file on Windows Mobile 6.5, but it does not appear to support printing the resulting PDF. Can anyone recommend a way to print a saved PDF file from the mobile device?

I've searched the net and I'm failing miserably to locate a SDK that will let me do this. The application is written in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this 3rd party library http://www.fieldsoftware.com/PrinterCE_NetCF.htm .

Not sure it can be used to print a PDF, but you can use the library to print directly on a selection of printers.  Do you need the PDF file?

Comment: This looks good, thanks. I'm just not sure I will be able to get the licensing past the powers that be. We're after a library we can just use and this one is based on numbers of installs. That just gives us an admin nightmare that we can do without.